# What if I change the pathname of a git repository?

Tags: git

I have a directory `project` contains a `.git` directory. Do I need to do anything

- if I change the pathname of `project` (not including the name `project`)? (e.g. move `project` to be under another directory)
- if I change the pathname of `project` (including the name `project`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are safe to rename `project` directory and / or move it anywhere, if:

- you are not using relative paths in the project, pointing outside of `project` directory
- no other repository point to `project` as a remote

Git repositories are self-contained and store everything needed within `.git` subdirectory.